# How do I get nginx to log and drop unconfigured virtual hosts?

Tags: nginx

I've got an nginx installation that serves a couple of virtual hosts; these are working fine. However, I seem to recall that this server is responsible for hosting a couple of other websites. I can't recall which ones.

I don't want these requests to resolve to the default (arbitrary) vhost.

At the moment, for example, going to `http://10.0.0.10/` (the internal address) resolves to the default vhost. This vhost is running drupal, and -- because drupal doesn't recognise the vhost -- it brings up the drupal installation instructions. I'm concerned that this is happening to other, external names that resolve to this server.

**Is there a way to set up nginx so that it logs and drops requests that don't exactly match a configured vhost?**

Alternatively, I guess, the question could be phrased: "How do I set up a default vhost that matches all unknown names? And how do I configure that vhost to log and drop accesses?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a default catch all server and log requests to a specific file and return some status or other. Your other known servers can be configured with known server_name values.

```
    log_format with_host '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                        '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$host"';

    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            location / {
                  access_log /var/log/nginx/unknown_site.log with_host;
                  return 404;       
            }
    }

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name drupal.com;                   
            location / {
                ....         
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'd ignore the `server_name`, it would work with or without it, other than that the config is correct.

Comment: Note - Roger edited this so @MohammadAbuShady comment no longer applies.